# Which way is more common in Professional Environment?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am a newcomer to Dart - Flutter and doesn't have any professional experiences working as developer in a team. So I want to ask a simple question about these two expressions:

```
if (components.contains('A')) {
    } else {
      components.add('A');
    }

components.contains('A')
    ? () {}()
    : components.add('A');
```

Which one is the more preferred in a professional environment or team way? I have read couple of articles basically talking about reducing `if - else` usage in writing code but IMO `if - else` way is more readable (I'm not sure what this `? :` expression is called) but I am just a newbie tho.

Comment: `?:` is called a ternary operator

Comment: to add more, If you have multiple `if-else` then you should use `switch-case`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are same dear. You dont have to worry about it that much. Let me compare those two.

Ternary operator (`?` `:`):

Great for readability when you have to assign value to a variable based on a condition.

You must handle both cases `true` and `false` with ternary.

If you have simple condition this is the great way. In flutter you can do something like this:

```
bool isLoading = false;
//...

return Container(
  child: isLoading ? CircularProgressIndicator() : Text("data"),
)
```

`if` - `else`:

Is more convenient when you want to do multiple things based on a condition. And if you want to check multiple conditions you can use `else if`.

If you just want to handle `true` or `false`, you can only use `if` without `else` block which you cannot do with ternary.

Same above example if you do with `if`:

```
bool isLoading = false;
//...
if (isLoading) { // with or without bracket if one line
  // you can have any other computations here but cannot do it with ternary
  return Container(
    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
  );
} else {
  return Container(
    child: Text("data"),
  );
}
```

In this case you can say ternary is the most readable and convenient approach.

So the readability comes based on the place and the logic you have. Not from the `if`-`else` or turnary operator.

Comment: hm.. I think I didn't give much thoughts on other ways of implementing them before. Thanks for pointing out those things

Answer (score 1):

Both approaches are the same in this case. I can event suggest following to do the same:

```dart
if (!components.contains('A')) {
   components.add('A');
}
```

you can omit the `if` part if it doesn't do anything. Instead, by reversing the condition you can do the same work without an additional blank portion.

I'd like to point out that if you have only a single statement to execute based a small condition you should go for `?:`(ternary operator) since the code seems much clearer than using `if-else` for the same.

There's a limitation in ternary operator though, that you can not omit any of the parts. While you can only use `if` block without an `else` block.

I would always choose the approach which makes my code, easily readable and helps me figure out what is being done just by taking a glance at it.